# Automatically assign each element from an array to a variable

Tags: perl

I have an array that I populate automatically after doing a database query.

So I have for example `@array` whose length will vary in size depending on the result from the database query. I want to assign each element of the array to a different variable.

For example:

```
my $length = @array;
```

If length equals 3 then 3 variables should be created automatically with the elements of the array assigned to them in this order.

```
$var1 = $array[0];
$var2 = $array[1];
$var3 = $array[2];
```

Comment: Why? The point of arrays is that they stop you from having to create separate variables for each of a group of items.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? Its a rather silly thing to do, and quite redundant.

Comment: Why? Just use `$array[1]` instead of `$var2`; it is much more flexible! If you want to give meaningful names to the values, you can use list assignment: `my($id, $name, $age) = @$row;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If length equals 3 then 3 variables should be created automatically with the elements of the array assigned to them in this order.

No, variables should definitely not be created in this fashion.

[Why it's stupid to "use a variable as a variable name"](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

---

On the off chance of a communication failure, perhaps you are looking for the following:

```
my ($id, $name, $address, $phone) = @$row;
```

Later variables will be undef if `@$row` contains too few fields.